# Meteor client integration async testing with Velocity / Jasmine; How to get return value?

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

*Updated: User count before and after signup still failing*

Trying to test a new user signing up through the UI (see jQuery "signUp"). Users count from Method.call("usersCount") before and after signup both return 'undefined'.

I see 'undefined' -> user object -> 'undefined' in log. Not sure why user count is not getting assigned to the variable(s) in the spec code.

Second test checking the signup/logged-in users passes.

**/tests/jasmine/client/integration/spec.js**

```
// New user signup
function signUp (user, callback) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
    $('#signup-link').trigger('click');
    $('#login-username').val(user.username);
    $('#login-password').val(user.password);
    $('#login-password-again').val(user.password);
    $('#login-buttons-password').trigger('click');
    callback;
}

describe('User signup', function() {

    var user = { username: 'larry', password: 'password' };

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        Meteor.call("clearDB", done);
    });

    it('should increase users by one', function (done) {
        var userCountBefore = Meteor.call("usersCount");
        var userCountAfter = signUp(user, Meteor.call("usersCount"));
        expect(userCountBefore + 1).toEqual(userCountAfter);
    });

    it('should automatically log-in new user', function () {
        expect(Meteor.user().username).toEqual(user.username);
    });
});
```

**/packages/test-helpers.js** (*custom debug testing package; clearDB method from* [https://gist.github.com/qnub/97d828f11c677007cb07][1])

```
  if ((typeof process !== 'undefined') && process.env.IS_MIRROR) {
  Meteor.methods({
    usersCount: function () {
        var count = Meteor.users.find({}).count();
        return count;
    },
    clearDB: function(){
      console.log('Clear DB');

      var collectionsRemoved = 0;
      var db = Meteor.users.find()._mongo.db;
      db.collections(function (err, collections) {

        // Filter out velocity and system.indexes from collections
        var appCollections = _.reject(collections, function (col) {
          return col.collectionName.indexOf('velocity') === 0 ||
            col.collectionName === 'system.indexes';
        });

        // Remove each collection
        _.each(appCollections, function (appCollection) {
          appCollection.remove(function (e) {
            if (e) {
              console.error('Failed removing collection', e);
              fut.return('fail: ' + e);
            }
            collectionsRemoved++;
            console.log('Removed collection');
            if (appCollections.length === collectionsRemoved) {
              console.log('Finished resetting database');
            }
          });
        });

      });

      console.log('Finished clearing');
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Do you subscribe to the users? All the Meteor.calls are async. So use callback handlers. And don't expose the Meteor methods to the client.

Comment: No, I wasn't subscribed to users, because I didn't need them in the rest of my app. Is subscribing to them in the test better than calling a Meteor method that queries the db for users' count? As for method calls, would the pattern looks something like this: `Meteor.call(“method name”, function() { —do stuff to test—});` ...? By the way, per your suggestion I've moved the test helpers to their own deBug-only package ... right? @Sanjo

Comment: Meteor.calls are async. You need to pass a callback.

Comment: I do this `var userCountBefore = Meteor.call("usersCount", function(err, result) { alert(result); });` and it still gives me undefined. Is this not what you are saying? Sorry I'm new at this. @Sanjo

Comment: Now trying this, which logs the correct value from inside the function, but still returns 'undefined' ...`var userCountBefore;
        Meteor.call("usersCount", function(error, count) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                userCountBefore = count;
                console.log(userCountBefore);
            };
        });` @Sanjo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is one way to solve this:

```
it('should increase users by one', function (done) {
    Meteor.call("usersCount", function(error, userCountBefore) {
        signUp(user);
        Meteor.call("usersCount", function (error, userCountAfter) {
            expect(userCountAfter).toEqual(userCountBefore + 1);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Future viewers, checkout the following links for reference/alternate approaches:
    https://github.com/caolan/async
    https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/async
    http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Thanks to @sanjo for helping me see the light!